# Does DateTieredCompactionStrategy work with composite keys?

Tags: database, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Does DateTieredCompactionStrategy in Apache Cassandra 2.1.2. work with a compound clustering key?

More specifically, like with this table where (timestamp, hash) makes up a compound clustering key:

```
CREATE TABLE sensordata (
    timeblock int,
    timestamp timestamp,
    hash int,
    data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (timeblock, timestamp, hash)
)
```

I believe, that the DateTieredCompactionStrategy would work for `PRIMARY KEY (timeblock, timestamp)` -- but does it also work for `PRIMARY KEY (timeblock, timestamp, hash)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DTCS will just merge similar aged tables during compaction. It doesn't really care about your PK. As all rows for your example will still be clustered by timestamp, you should be fine.

Comment: So the age is not derived from the timestamp (column header), but from the actual time of write (system time) ?

Comment: Age is derived from most recent/oldest timestamp from any value of a sstable. These upper/lower bound age values will be used for bucketing tables. But those timestamps are neither the timestamp when the table was flushed to disk or any column value in your data model. Keep in mind that each column value in Cassandra has its own associated timestamp whether its an actual timestamp type or text or any other datatype.